# python regular expressions instead of splitting

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"(98119,m1) (229260,m1) (15652,m2)"
```

The above can be an arbitrary number of elements (only 3 in my example)

I want to return a string that looks like this

```
"98119 229260 15652"
```

I can use string splitting but this will be too much code. I am looking into regular expressions instead but Regex is not really something I am good at. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> mystr = "(98119,m1) (229260,m1) (15652,m2)"
>>> ' '.join(findall('\(([^,]+),', mystr))
'98119 229260 15652'
>>>
```

Here is a breakdown of what the Regex pattern used above matches:

```
\(     # (
(      # The start of a capture group
[^,]+  # One or more characters that are not ,
)      # The close of the capture group
,      # ,
```

Comment: or just a simple "2 digits or more", i.e. `'(\d{2,})'`